# Exoplayer - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Player is accessed on the wrong thread

Tags: java, kotlin, audio, media-player, exoplayer

**AudioPlayer.kt**

```
class AudioPlayerImplementation(
internal val context: Application
) : AudioPlayer,
Player.Listener,
LoadEventController {

private var playerBase: ExoPlayer? = null
private val player: ExoPlayer
    get() {
        if (playerBase == null) {
            playerBase = createPlayer(this)
        }
        return playerBase ?: throw IllegalStateException("Could not create an 
audio player")
    }
  
   override fun play(startAtPosition: Long?) {
    startAtPosition ?: return player.play()
    player.seekTo(startAtPosition)
    //error thrown here
    player.play()
    }

   override fun seekTo(position: Long) {
    //error thrown here
    player.seekTo(position)
   }
 }
```

Inside that same class this is the function: **createPlayer**

```
private fun createPlayer(owner: AudioPlayerImplementation): ExoPlayer {
    return SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context)
        .setLoadControl(LoadController().apply {
            eventController = owner
        })
        .build().apply {
            val attr = AudioAttributes.Builder().apply {
                setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
            }.build()

            setAudioAttributes(attr, false)
            setPriorityTaskManager(PriorityTaskManager())
            addListener(owner)
        }
   }
```

When I play any media, I get this error:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Player is accessed on the wrong thread.
Current thread: 'ExoPlayer:Playback'
Expected thread: 'main'**

I read that you need to use a Handler so I changed fun:

```
 override fun seekTo(position: Long) {
    val mainThreadHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    mainThreadHandler.post { player.seekTo(position) }
}
```

I cant write this code in every instance player...there are so many instances.

NB: I use Hilt.
Best way to structure and build exoplayer instance?

Comment: did you find the answer for this ?

Comment: did you find the answer for this ?